# Why Opensource projects don't include notice and copyright information of dependent libraries having permissive license?

Tags: mit, permissive

Many of the Opensource projects which use libraries which have a permissive license, doesn't include copyright and license information. For eg: Requests project (https://github.com/psf/requests) uses Pytest (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest) (which uses MIT license) but still, Requests project doesn't include its copyright and license information of Pytest.

Please help me with the above query.

Comment: Right, what exactly is your problem? If the repository does not contain the library code, but has them as build requirements, why should it contain anything from their libraries?

Comment: What does "Requests project *uses* Pytest" actually mean? Do they distribute a copy of PyTest? If so, then yes they would need to include that information as well, if they don't then copyright doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks @planetmaker and Felix G for the quick response and helping me with the query. After going through many articles and reading license multiple times, it became clear to me that license copy is only required if we are distributing the end application in the form of binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requirement to have a copy of the MIT license and `pytest` copyrights only applies to those sites/repositories that actually host a copy of `pytest` itself.

What many open-source projects do is that they don't contain the code for their dependencies, but only a configuration file that instructs a package manager to retrieve the relevant dependencies from the official location where those dependencies are hosted. The location where `pip` retrieves `pytest` from *is* required to have the copyright and licensing information.

Having a `Pipfile` mentioning `pytest` is a far cry from having an actual copy of `pytest` in your repository.